# Is there a way to edit an excel VBA macro in Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba, visual-studio

I would like to edit my Excel macro in Visual studio as it is easier to read and stuff, is there a way that i can change the default editor to visual basic.

Comment: You could do it in the VB6 IDE by exporting the modules to `.bas` files and opening them there. You cannot do it in VS.NET.

Comment: Thanks Hadn't thought about that!

Comment: The only thing is that it is a longer work around. was wondering of there was any way of changing the default program.

Comment: If it is just editing, then you can right click the on the bas file and open it in VB.Net or even Notepad++. Obviously you will not have access to Intellisense but the greatest advantage of right-clicking and opening it in VB.Net is that your code get auto indented and not to mention the Autocomplete of If-Endifs etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a tool called [`SourceTools.xla`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18029/SourceTools-xla) that allows quick export of all source code into appropriate files (.bas, .frm, .cls,..) and then you can edit the files with your favorite editor.

You can then update the VBA project from the edited files, and most importantly keep track of the source file in your favorite source control system (SVN, Git).

Example .xls file with exported source code in a similarly named sub folder

[image: scr1]

Export code from VBA

[image: scr2]

and the files it created

[image: scr3]

and changing the text with an outside editor.

[image: scr4]

Unfortunately, the automated import back into VBA is buggy, and I have to resort to manually copy and pasting code with `Ctrl-A`, `Ctrl-C` in the editor and `Ctrl-A`, `Ctrl-V` in VBA.

But the import into SVN works well with TortoiseSVN to keep track of changes in code.

---

<sub>You will have to go in the code and change `C:\Programme\TortoiseSVN\bin\` into `C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\`.</sub>